# What are the tags used by most users?

Tags: discussion, statistics

What are the top tags, ordered by the number of users that have applied them at least once?

Answer (score 4):

I would have guessed that this would be the same order as the number of questions by tag ranking you see on the tags page, but it turns out there are some significant differences.

A [data explorer query](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/454/tags-by-number-of-users-that-used-them) for example shows that `[javascript]` users on average only ask 2.26 question on SO, while `[php]` users ask 3.06. So there are actually less Php users than Javascript users, they just ask more questions. There are several such rather big differences in the top tags.

Comment: Nice; I tried writing one and couldn't get it right

Comment: @Michael Mrozek: In pseudo-SQL, it would be SELECT Count(tags) AS times_used FROM tags JOIN questions JOIN users GROUP BY users.id ORDER BY times_used

Answer (score 0):

- https://stackoverflow.com/tags
- https://superuser.com/tags
- https://serverfault.com/tags
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags

You can see the numbers next to each tag, sorted from most to least popular (well, only the top x tags).

Comment: Those are the number of instances of the tag, not the number of unique users that have used the tag at least once

Comment: Sorry, that was not how I had read your question.

Comment: sth's query's 2nd column would answer it, though. Right?